# Django Filter timestamp data GROUP BY day, week, month, year

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-filters

I have an django(DRF) app in which I storing periodic timeseries data based on API response. Here is my 
model.py

```
# Model to store the Alexa API Data
class Alexa(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    extra = jsonfield.JSONField(null=True)
    rank =  models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)
```

I am using django-filters to query data based on a range (__lte, __gte). 
Like `/api/alexa/?created_at__lte=2020-02-14T09:15:52.329641Z` return all the data created before `2020-02-14T09:15:52.329641Z`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-02-03T19:30:57.868588Z",
        "extra": "{'load_time': 00, 'backlink': 0}",
        "rank": 0
    },
    ...
 ]
```

Is there a way to build an endpoint to return aggregated data grouped by day, week, month and year based on the query params I pass. For example,
`/api/alexa/?created_at__lte=2020-02-14T09:15:52.329641Z&group_by=month` would return

```
[
    {
        "created_at": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "extra": "{'load_time': 00, 'backlink': 0}", <- Aggregated Data 
        "rank": 0                                    <- Aggregated Data
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-02-01T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "extra": "{'load_time': 00, 'backlink': 0}", <- Aggregated Data 
        "rank": 0                                    <- Aggregated Data 
    },
 ]
```

Here's my current views.py

```
class AlexaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Alexa.objects.all()
    filter_fields = {'created_at' : ['iexact', 'lte', 'gte']}
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head']
```

I have seen several snippets doing aggregation but none completely fulfilling my requirements nor giving me a complete idea about the topic.

I am new to Django and building analytics dashboards in general, if there are any other way of representing such timeseries data for consumption in front-end graphs, I would appreciate your suggestions to that as well.

EDIT :
Here is my serializer.py

```
class AlexaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Alexa
         fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the class `AlexaViewSet` is not a serializer but a ViewSet. You didn't specify the serializer class on that ViewSet so I you need to specify that.

On the other side, if you want to pass a custom query param on the URL then you should override the `list` method of this ViewSet and parse the query string passed in the `request` object to retrieve the value of `group_by`, validate it, and then perfom the aggregation youself.

Another problem that I see is that you also need to define what is to aggregate a JSON field, which is not supported in SQL and it's very relative, so you may want to consider redesigning how you store the information of this JSON field if you want to perfom aggregations on fields inside it. I would suggest extracting the fields you want to aggregate from the JSON (when storing them in the database) and put them in a SQL column separately so you could perform aggregations later.
The client could also pass the agregation operation as a query parameter, for example `aggregation=sum` or `aggregation=avg`.

In a simple case, where you just need the average of the ranks this should be useful as an example (you could add `TruncQuarter`, etc.):

```py
class AlexaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AlexaSerializer
    queryset = Alexa.objects.all()
    filter_fields = {'created_at': ['iexact', 'lte', 'gte']}
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head']

    GROUP_CASTING_MAP = {  # Used for outputing the reset datetime when grouping
        'day': Cast(TruncDate('created_at'), output_field=DateTimeField()),
        'month': Cast(TruncMonth('created_at'), output_field=DateTimeField()),
        'week': Cast(TruncWeek('created_at'), output_field=DateTimeField()),
        'year': Cast(TruncYear('created_at'), output_field=DateTimeField()),
    }

    GROUP_ANNOTATIONS_MAP = {  # Defines the fields used for grouping
        'day': {
            'day': TruncDay('created_at'),
            'month': TruncMonth('created_at'),
            'year': TruncYear('created_at'),
        },
        'week': {
            'week': TruncWeek('created_at')
        },
        'month': {
            'month': TruncMonth('created_at'),
            'year': TruncYear('created_at'),
        },
        'year': {
            'year': TruncYear('created_at'),
        },
    }

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group_by_field = request.GET.get('group_by', None)
        if group_by_field and group_by_field not in self.GROUP_CASTING_MAP.keys():  # validate possible values
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        if group_by_field:
            queryset = queryset.annotate(**self.GROUP_ANNOTATIONS_MAP[group_by_field]) \
                .values(*self.GROUP_ANNOTATIONS_MAP[group_by_field]) \
                .annotate(rank=Avg('rank'), created_at=self.GROUP_CASTING_MAP[group_by_field]) \
                .values('rank', 'created_at')

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

For these values:

```py
GET /alexa
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-03-16T12:04:59.096098Z",
        "extra": "{}",
        "rank": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "created_at": "2020-02-15T12:05:01.907920Z",
        "extra": "{}",
        "rank": 64
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "created_at": "2020-02-15T12:05:03.890150Z",
        "extra": "{}",
        "rank": 232
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-02-15T12:05:06.357748Z",
        "extra": "{}",
        "rank": 12
    }
]
```

```py
GET /alexa/?group_by=day
[
    {
        "created_at": "2020-02-15T00:00:00Z",
        "extra": null,
        "rank": 102
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-03-16T00:00:00Z",
        "extra": null,
        "rank": 2
    }
]
```

```py
GET /alexa/?group_by=week
[
    {
        "created_at": "2020-02-10T00:00:00Z",
        "extra": null,
        "rank": 102
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-03-16T00:00:00Z",
        "extra": null,
        "rank": 2
    }
]
```

```py
GET /alexa/?group_by=month
[
    {
        "created_at": "2020-02-01T00:00:00Z",
        "extra": null,
        "rank": 102
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-03-01T00:00:00Z",
        "extra": null,
        "rank": 2
    }
]
```

```py
GET /alexa/?group_by=year
[
    {
        "created_at": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "extra": null,
        "rank": 77
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response, I understood your approach! Could you help me understand why this error? I got this while trying out the above code. I have added my serializer, in case it is relevant
 
```AttributeError at /api/alexa/
'dict' object has no attribute 'extra'```

Comment: I'm glad you could understand it. Could you give me more details about your error? Maybe the whole stacktrace will help.

Comment: As far as I believe, the error seems to be that my serializer is expecting an 'extra' attribute in dict. When ever I exclude it from my serializer using `exclude = ['extra']` every thing seems to work as expected. 
Here is the full [stack trace](http://dpaste.com/082J189)